# Send org buffer as email attachment

Tags: email

I am working on a function that sends the current buffer as an email attachment. Here is my code

```
(defun my/buffer-to-ipad ()
  "Send current buffer as email attachment to iPad via email"
  (interactive)
  (mail)
  (mail-to)
  (insert "my@ipad.de")
  (mail-subject)
  (insert "Notes from Emacs")
  (mml-attach-buffer (buffer-name (other-buffer)) "text/plain" "notes" "attachment"))
```

Calling my function creates the following email.
[image]

However, the received email just contains the following string as plain text without any attachments.
[image]

Creating the email manually with `(mml-attach-buffer)` works perfectly fine.
[image]

[image]

Why can't I just put `(mml-attach-buffer)` into my function? And what if my buffer name contains `<` or `>` characters? How can I escape them to avoid messing up the HTML in the email?